# How to send image through post using JSON in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a flutter app, which utilizes [image picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) to capture or select an image from the gallery, but I am having a hard time how to POST that image to my server from the client side.

From what I gathered, I can send the local image via JSON by converting an image file to bytes and then sending it as BASE64.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

Future<Map> _avatarSubmit() async {
    String url = api + '/api/account';
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Cookie": "MYCOOKIE=" + sessionCookie2 + "; MYTOKENS=" + sessionCookie3,
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    }, body: {
      "image": "",
    });
    Map content = JSON.decode(response.body);
    return content;
  }
```

My question is how to convert an image file in the device into bytes, so I can then use [crypto](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) plugin to convert it to BASE64?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [image picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) plugin provides the filePath of the image, you can use File class from dart:io to load the image and BASE64 from dart:convert to convert it as BASE64 string.

Here is how you can do it:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was the way to go. I just had to make sure to use  imagePath.toString().