# How to copy an image to clipboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, clipboard

I searched in google for how to copy an image to clipboard in flutter but I did not find any useful information. I only found in flutter documentation this:

"ClipboardData class:

Data stored on the system clipboard.

The system clipboard can contain data of various media types. This data structure currently supports only plain text data, in the text property."

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/ClipboardData-class.html

Is it impossible to copy an image to clipboard in flutter right now?

Comment: I am also looking for this use case. Given the lack of an answer here, and a cursory look at the code, it seems like it is not possible with the existing framework, and I cannot find a package which seems to support the clipboard with data types other than text. It is possible to create one using method channels, but is some work, I might have to try though.

Comment: @DanielBrotherston Any update if you got it working by a method channel

Answer (score 1):

I did not try and not sure if the answer is you looking for but you can give a try that first you can convert your image to  Uint8List format with BASE64 decode and encode then copy it. for conversion you can check this. link

[how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter)

also check answers of this threat

[how-to-send-image-through-post-using-json-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027418/how-to-send-image-through-post-using-json-in-flutter?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This package allows copying images to the clipboard:

https://github.com/superlistapp/super_native_extensions/tree/main/super_clipboard

```
    final item = DataWriterItem();
    item.add(Formats.png(imageData));
    await ClipboardWriter.instance.write([item]);
```

There's some other steps to follow to get it setup in their README, but I managed to get it working.