# Get The Image variable from the File Path and upload to backend in FileFormat in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file-format, imagepicker

I'm new to flutter and in an app I'm building I use ImagePicker plugin.
with that the file path image is viewed in my app after I get it from camera/gallery.
the image.path is like this

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files/Pictures/234d9437-8652-48de-a2b6-711b5f8b702d3492716976084944343.jpg

I need to get the image "234d9437-8652-48de-a2b6-711b5f8b702d3492716976084944343.jpg" part from that and send it to a backend db. I need to convert this before sending. Backend only accept Images in FileFormat.

How can get the image from the file path. in this case it's the variable _imageURI. Then from that retrieve the image and convert it into a FileFormat. After that I need to pass it to a Backend using a json POST request.

In my json request I have a field for 'image': that I need to set the value got from image selected in file format and set to there. how can do this?
can someone explain me with a code ?
much appreciated.

***My Code***

```
File _imageURI;
Future _getImageFromCamera() async {
var petImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera); //or gallery
setState(() {
      _imageURI = petImage;
      print(_imageURI.path);
  }
}
```

***Image Viewed as***

```
Container(
  width: 120.0,
  height: 120.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: new DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: new FileImage(
        _imageURI,
        scale: 1.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

***Json Request***

```
dogData = {
 {
  "user_email": "email@m.com,
  "user_token": "thisistoken",
  "pet": {
    "age": "integer",
    "birth_date": "%d %b %Y (01 JAN 1996)",
    "image": "!Swagger doesn't allow to put file upload. Use formdata instead of base64 in frontend module.",
    "name": "string",
    "sex": "string",
    "user_id": "id"
  }
}
```

***My API call***

```
final pet = await CallApi().createThePet(dogData, 'pets/create');
////
Future<dynamic> createThePet(data, apiUrl) async{
    var fullUrl = _baseUrl + apiUrl; // + await _getToken();
    final response = await http.post(fullUrl, body: jsonEncode(data), headers: _setHeaders());
....
```

Comment: so you have a `String` with value: `'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files/Pictures/234d9437-8652-48de-a2b6-711b5f8b702d3492716976084944343.jpg'` and you want to "cut" the file name part? if so, did you check `String` class official documentation?

Comment: you are suggesting me to trunk the begging of the string and get the rest of it? even with that, how can I convert this image into a file format to upload to a backend>?

Comment: *"I need to get the image "234d9437-8652-48de-a2b6-711b5f8b702d3492716976084944343.jpg" part"* - you wanted the filename part, didnt you? you did not say anything about uploading any file

Comment: apologies in the question format

Comment: You have a File _imageURI it's you image file can you please explain what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is called Multi-Part.
There isn't any definite piece of code for that in flutter so i am posting an example snippet.

```
Future<void> _uploadImage(File image) async {
String tempURL = https://YOUR_WEBSITE/upload";
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(tempURL));
request.headers["authorization"] = YOUR_TOKEN_HERE;
// prepare file to send.
var profilePhoto = http.MultipartFile(
    'upload', image.readAsBytes().asStream(), image.lengthSync(),
    filename: image.path);
request.files.add(profilePhoto);
try {
  // send files to server.
  var response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // now we will update the data with the
    response.stream.bytesToString().asStream().listen((data) {
      _updatePhoto(data);
    });
  } else {
    print("res status code in upload func : ${response.statusCode}");
  }
} catch (error) {
  print("Error : $error");
}
```

}

Comment: thanks Manish, I've also bumped into the term multipart when I try to research for a solution on this. will give your example a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,it is working fine with my project
**Install imagepicker,mime,http and import it**

```
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

**Initialize variable**

```
File _image;
final Imagepicker = ImagePicker();
```

**View for showing image after selecting**

```
Container(
                    width: 350,
                    height: 250,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[400], width: 1.0)),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 350,
                          height: 250,
                          child: _image == null
                              ? Text('No image selected.')
                              : Image.file(
                                  _image,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        getImage();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

**ImagePicker from camera**

```
    Future getImage() async {
        PickedFile image =
        await Imagepicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 1000);
    
        setState(() {
          _image = File(image.path);
        });
  }
```

**Submit Function**

```
     void submit(File image, String descrption) async {
          try {
                ///Spilits the path and returns only the filename and type
                
 final mimeTypeData =lookupMimeType(image.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');

    ///Url of your api

          final request =new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(Urls.ImageInsert));

    ///replace AreaImage with your database value

          final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('AreaImage', 
          image.path,contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));

    ///In case there is text fields or other details use like this
          request.fields['user_email'] = "Email";
          request.fields['user_token'] = "thisistoken";
         
          request.files.add(file);

          StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

        //waiting for response

        response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {

          //Response can be pass with map object to alertbox

          Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(value);
          try {
          
  // hide progrssbar
            pr.hide();

            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Alert"),
                  //here we show response message from api/or you can show your own message 
                 here
                  content: Text(map['message']),
                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Close"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //Do Something here
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          } catch (e) {
            e.toString();
          }
        });
      }
      
             }
         
         }
```

You can checkout my github for image upload with either gallery or camera[github](https://github.com/Abhijithsp/flutter-image_upload/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Comment: thanks for the amazing explanation. In my code I need to pass this image file into a json request body , I have updated my question relating to that, If you can suggest how can I pass the image file to that, will be much helpful.

Comment: i haven't don that,we use multipart requset to send file along with other values@JasonWaku

Comment: but i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027418/how-to-send-image-through-post-using-json-in-flutter @JasonWaku