# How do I submit images I have picked from gallery as part of a form I have already made

Tags: android, flutter, forms, dart, mobile

```
final idDocument =
    await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final avatar = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final utilityBill =
    await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

This are the images I want to submit.

Comment: Submit to what? Firebase? Http put?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send image through post using JSON in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027418/how-to-send-image-through-post-using-json-in-flutter)